# input field triggers watcher from another component

Tags: vue.js, watch

I am very new to vuejs and I am having troubke understanding how the watcher is being triggered on page load by an input field that is inside the parent component.

I have placed a watcher inside the barChart component to make my options reactive:

```js
import {
  Bar,
  mixins
} from 'vue-chartjs'
export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('bar chart mounted')
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  },
  watch: {
    'options': {
      handler(newOption, oldOption) {
        console.log('watcher')
        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
}
```

I use this chart inside another component like so:

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <h2> Popular times </h2>
        <h5>How busy it might be on a given week day</h5>
        <section>
            <form  style="display: flex" method="get">
                  <div style="margin: 5px">
                      <el-select
                           :placeholder="form.day"
                           :class="['select-default']"
                           v-bind:value="form.day"
                           v-model="form.day"
                           @input="loadData"
                           name="day"
                      >
                      <el-option v-for="option in days"
                          :value="option.id"
                          :label="option.day"
                          :key="option.id"
                      >
                      </el-option>
                      </el-select>
                  </div>
    
                  <!-- start date -->
                  <div style="margin: 5px">
                        <div class="el-select select-default">
                          <div class="el-input el-input--suffix">
                           <input class="el-input__inner"
                            v-model="form.dt_start"
                            :max="maxDate"
                            @input="loadData"
                            type="date"
                            placeholder="start date"
                            name="date_start"
                           >
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
    
                  <!-- end date -->
                  <div style="margin: 5px">
                        <div class="el-select select-default">
                          <div class="el-input el-input--suffix">
                           <input class="el-input__inner"
                                  type="date"
                                  :max="maxDate"
                                  v-model="form.dt_end"
                                  @input="loadData"
                                  placeholder="date_end"
                           >
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <!-- work space -->
                  <div style="margin: 5px">
                        <SelectWidget
                        id="machine-workspace"
                        url="/api/workspace_core/workspace/"
                        placeholder="select workspace"
                        @input="loadData"
                        v-model="form.workspace"
                        />
                        <br>
                  </div>
    
                  <!--user group -->
                  <div style="margin: 5px">
                      <SelectWidget
                      id="user-group"
                      url="/api/usergroup_core/usergroup/"
                      placeholder="select user group"
                      @input="loadData"
                      v-model="form.user_group"
                      />
                      <br>
                  </div>
    
                 <!-- machine family -->
                  <div style="margin: 5px">
                      <GroupedMultiSelectWidget
                      url="/api/machine_core/machinefamily/"
                      group_by_key="workspace"
                      group_label_key="name"
                      url2="/api/workspace_core/workspace/"
                      placeholder="select machine families"
                      @input="loadData"
                      v-model="form.machine_family"
                      />
                  </div>
            </form>
        </section>
          <br>
          <div v-if="!loadedWheel"><loading-main-panel/></div>
         <BarChart v-if="loaded"
                  :chart-data="chartData"
                  :options="chartOptions"
                  :height ="90"
        />
        <br>
      </div>
    </template>
```

```js
import BarChart from "./BarChart";
import Dropdown from "../../components/Library/UIComponents/Dropdown"
import GroupedMultiSelectWidget from "~/components/widgets/GroupedMultiSelectWidget"
import SelectWidget from "../../components/widgets/SelectWidget";
import DateInput from "../../components/Library/UIComponents/Inputs/DateInput";
import LoadingMainPanel from "../../components/general/LoadingMainPanel";
export default {
  name: 'PopularChart',
  components: {
    BarChart,
    DateInput,
    Dropdown,
    SelectWidget,
    GroupedMultiSelectWidget,
    LoadingMainPanel
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: `/api/data_app/job_count_by_hour/`,
      loadedWheel: false,
      loaded: false,
      maxDate: this.getToday(),
      form: {
        day: 'Today',
        workspace: '',
        machine_family: [],
        duration: [],
        user_group: [],
        dt_start: '',
        dt_end: ''
      },
      days: [{
          day: "Today",
          id: "Today"
        },
        {
          day: "Monday",
          id: "0"
        },
        {
          day: "Tuesday",
          id: "1"
        },
        {
          day: "Wednesday",
          id: "2"
        },
        {
          day: "Thursday",
          id: "3"
        },
        {
          day: "Friday",
          id: "4"
        },
        {
          day: "Saturday",
          id: "5"
        },
        {
          day: "sunday",
          id: "6"
        }],
      chartData: {},
      chartOptions: {},
      maximumValue: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getToday() {
      let today = new Date();
      let dd = today.getDate();
      let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
      let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
      }
      if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
      }
      today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
      return today
    },
    updateChart(data, maxValue) {
      this.chartData = {
        labels: ["00u", "1u", "2u", "3u", "4u", "5u", "6u", "7u", "8u", "9u", "10u", "11u", "12u", "13u", "14u", "15u", "16u", "17", "18u", "19u", "20u", "21u", "22u", "23u"],
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: '#f93232',
            data: data
                }
              ]
      }
      this.maximumValue = maxValue
      this.chartOptions = {
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, ) {
              if (tooltipItems.value > ((50 / 100) * maxValue)) {
                return ' busy';
              } else if (tooltipItems.value < ((50 / 100) * maxValue) && tooltipItems.value > ((30 / 100) * maxValue)) {
                return ' kind of busy';
              }
              if (tooltipItems.value < ((30 / 100) * maxValue)) {
                return 'not so busy'
              }
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              zeroLineColor: "transparent",
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              callbacks: {},
              max: this.maximumValue,
              display: false,
              stepSize: 100
            }
              }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              zeroLineColor: "transparent",
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
              }],
        },
      }
    },
    async loadData() {
      this.loadedWheel = false
      await this.$axios.get(`${this.url}?day=${this.form.day}&date_start=${this.form.dt_start}&date_end=${this.form.dt_end}&workspace=${this.form.workspace}&user_group=${this.form.user_group}&machine_family=${this.form.machine_family}`).then(response => {
        this.updateChart(response.data.results, response.data.maximum_factor)
        this.loaded = true
        this.loadedWheel = true
      })
    },
    mounted() {
      this.loadData()
    }
  },
}
```

Then I place this last component inside another one to be able to display multiple charts:

```html
    <template>
      <section>
        <PopularChart/>
        <br>
        <ChartMachines/>
      </section>
    </template>

    <script>
    import ChartMachines from "./ChartMachines";
    import PopularChart from "./PopularChart";
    export default {
     name: 'Charts',
      components: {ChartMachines,PopularChart},
    
    }
    </script>
```

After examining my code I found that the reason as to why the watcher was being called on page load came from the `GroupedMultiSelectWidget`. I have no idea how to fix this and why it is even happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is.

The watcher gets triggered on the component creation because a value is being changed (from `undefined` to the given prop value).

It it indeed triggered from `GroupedMultiSelectWidget` because :

1. `GroupedMultiSelectWidget` gets mounted
2. `GroupedMultiSelectWidget` triggers an `input` event (probably emitted on the component initialization, I do not know this component's inner workings), which calls `loadData`
3. The `loadData` method sets `loadedWheel` to `false` and `loaded` to `true`, thus starting the creation of your `BarChart` component
4. The component gets created and receives the prop values, triggering the deep watcher on your prop.

Comment: but that component should not trigger loadData() no? it has its own method that triggers an api call to get data

Comment: it is very very strange, but i had to change the `@input` event in the child component to a `@change` component.. thanks for trying to answer my question!